# Why is the height calculation so inconsistent in Gecko and Blink when dealing with inline-block elements?

Tags: html, css, gecko, blink

As you can see below, both Gecko and Blink performs an inconsistent height calculation for different inline-block elements, even though they all have the same css class. It seems like <sup>(*pause*)</sup> Trident is the only layout engine to get it right.

Did I forget to (re)set a property?

Furthermore, as you can see in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kringsjaa/qamzmz0t/)**, if I change the padding from `.3em` to `1em` Blink renders as expected. All elements gets the same height. Gecko is still "broken" though.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

---

```
<a> <button> <input> <span>
```

---

**Gecko** (Firefox v. 39.0)

[image: Gecko]

---

**Blink** (Google Chrome v. 43.0.2357.132 m):

[image: Blink]

---

**Trident** (Internet Explorer v. 11.0.9600.17843):

[image: Trident]

---

```css
body {
    font: normal 15px arial;
    padding: 1em;
}

.button {
    background: #444444;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 1em;
    height: auto;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 1em;
    padding: .3em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#">button</a><button class="button">button</button><input class="button" type="button" value="button" /><span class="button">button</span>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For **Gecko** (Firefox), it is due to borders on `::moz-focus-inner` for form elements. If you notice, the form elements (`input` and `button`) are always ~2px wider and taller than other elements.

To solve it, always add this to your CSS (as part of your reset):

```
button::-moz-focus-inner{
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:-2px;
    margin-bottom:-2px;
}
input::-moz-focus-inner{
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:-2px;
    margin-bottom:-2px;
}
```

The negative margins are necessary so that the font displays "correctly" in the line-height. You may need to tweak the values to fit your line-height, but these values mostly work fine.

For **Blink** (Chrome), the elements are actually the same size, but the only issue is that they are "mis-aligned". You'll notice that sometimes the form elements display slightly lower than the others in an `inline-block` setting. To solve it, simply ensure that they all use the same vertical alignment, e.g.:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

It is always a good practice to declare the two properties above **together** - if you specify inline-block, always remember to specify the vertical alignment, in order to prevent misalignment.

Comment: Great! Just a note: Your Gecko fix made it even worse. However, if I remove the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` properties everything looks perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Yups, the margin-top and bottom may need to be tweaked according to individual use-cases (sometimes 0 works best). It depends on a few things like your `box-sizing`, `line-height` etc. I normally use `border-box` and `px` heights, and `-2px` works. If not, please experiment with it, and once you find a setting that's good, use it as part of your "reset" and forget about it.